# how to implement Microsoft Excel Percentile Function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
=PERCENTILE(O2:O29, 0.2)
```

The above formula is Microsoft excel percentile formula, which i want to convert into MySQL.

I have a users table where with column name no_of_visits.The column contains random values for e.g 1,2,3,4,2,5,7,2,4,6,8....I want to find 0.2 percentile of this column.

Please provide mysql query to find 0.2 PERCENTILE of the column.

Please if anybody can help me it would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you define percentile? Please don't point to excel documentation that doesn't define it either.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use `offset` and `limit`.  This requires that you know the number of rows in the table.  For instance, if you want the 20th percentile and there are 100 rows in the table, then:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.val
offset 19 limit 1;
```

You can parameterize the "19" and `n * <percentile> - 1`.